# Not able to create a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I was trying to create a new collection in the below format in MongoDB. But I am not able to do so.

Below is my collection creation code.Can anyone please try out the same bunch of code & try creating a collection. Please help me with the same. Thanking in advance.

```
db.MasterAccount_AccountUser.insert
(
 {
MasterAccountID: 100,
MasterAccountName: 'LMS Plumber Inc',
AccountOwner: 'John',
AccountUser:[
         {
        AccountUserID: 1001,
        AccountUserName: 'John',
        AccountUserRole: 'Admin',
        AccountUserEmailID: 'john@lms.com',
        AccountUserPhoneNumber: '8132546363'
             },
         {
        AccountUserID: 1002,
        AccountUserName: 'Matt',
        AccountUserRole: 'User', 
        AccountUserEmailID: 'matt@lms.com',
        AccountUserPhoneNumber: '8132546362'
         },
         {
        AccountUserID: 1003,
        AccountUserName: 'Dan',
        AccountUserRole: 'User',
        AccountUserEmailID: 'dan@lms.com',
        AccountUserPhoneNumber: '8132568945'
         }  
        ]       
  }
)
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks.With your revised block of code, this time the code runs well without any error. But when I ask for "show.collections", it would not show me the new collection name ie. MasterAccount_AccountUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being treated as two separate statements by the shell.

The first being `db.MasterAccount_AccountUser.insert`, and the second statement being the remainder of your code. Simply moving up the `(` to the first line will cause it to treat the entire thing as one statment. Like so:

```
db.MasterAccount_AccountUser.insert(
 {
MasterAccountID: 100,
MasterAccountName: 'LMS Plumber Inc',
AccountOwner: 'John',
AccountUser:[
         {
        AccountUserID: 1001,
        AccountUserName: 'John',
        AccountUserRole: 'Admin',
        AccountUserEmailID: 'john@lms.com',
        AccountUserPhoneNumber: '8132546363'
             },
         {
        AccountUserID: 1002,
        AccountUserName: 'Matt',
        AccountUserRole: 'User', 
        AccountUserEmailID: 'matt@lms.com',
        AccountUserPhoneNumber: '8132546362'
         },
         {
        AccountUserID: 1003,
        AccountUserName: 'Dan',
        AccountUserRole: 'User',
        AccountUserEmailID: 'dan@lms.com',
        AccountUserPhoneNumber: '8132568945'
         }  
        ]       
  }
)
```

Comment: This is due to the JavaScript Syntax. You can verify this with JsLint (http://www.jslint.com/). It will show you that there's a missing ( directly after the method name.